# How do I associate notification mail reply to user's inbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, notifications

I have an Rails web-application where a user can send message to any other registered user. Once a user sends a message to another user, another user gets a notification on application and also by email in his/her personal email inbox (Like basecamp).

I want to implement this functionality where if a user reply to a message from his/her personal email inbox(say gmail/yahoo), the message becomes available in the application and receiver gets a notification as usual.

As I could understand, we’ll need to associate a unique id and set it as reply-to field in notification mail. Any help in the right way to approach this problem will be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We are already using sendgrid. And sendgrid provides [web-hook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/index.html) for emails. Which is quite easy to integrate with a rails application. It also uses mails gem. I'll keep posted if I find anything new on this.

I'm still working on finding out how to associate unique id in reply-to field in email. Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Chandan